# seeking clarity regarding the 'world_frame' parameter in ekf_localization node

Tags: localization, navigation, ekf, ros-melodic, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have spawned two husky bots  (namespaced `husky_1` and `husky_2`) in the `Gazebo` world. I am using two `ekf_localization` nodes (from the robot_localization package) to produce the `husky_1/odom -> husky_1/base_link` and `husky_2/odom -> husky_2/base_link` transform.

The `ekf_localization` node loads the parameters from a `localization.yaml` file.

This file has 2 parameters named `odom_frame` and `world_frame`.  I understand what I need to set as odom_frame.

I am seeking clarity regarding what needs to be go in the `world_frame` parameter - when should we use `odom` and when should we use `map`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372051/seeking-clarity-regarding-the-%27world_frame%27-parameter-in-ekf_localization-node/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be `odom` when when you want to generate the odom->base_link tf and it should be `map` when you want to generate the map->odom tf.

This is spelled out in the [docs](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#frame).

Cheers!
JB

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-18**:
Would be there be a difference in the transform published by the `ekf_localization` node in the two cases?
What I mean is, would the `ekf_localization` node publish `odom ->base_link` transform in one case, and `map -> base_link` transform in the other?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-18**:
By convention you should never publish map -> base link directly. I answered that exactly in my answer.

```
It should be odom when when you want to generate the odom->base_link tf and it should be map when you want to generate the map->odom tf.
```

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-19**:
The [docs](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html) say the following about the `publish_tf` parameter -

`If true, the state estimation node will publish the transform from the frame specified by the world_frame parameter to the frame specified by the base_link_frame parameter. Defaults to true.`

So, if we set the `world_frame` as `/map`, then the `ekf_localization` node would (by default) publish the `/map -> /base_link` transform.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-19**:
That is a very good point. I could be 2000% wrong, but in my experience that is not how it works OR is intended to work. I made a [PR to the docs](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/pull/623) That either is correct, or will get rejected with an explanation that makes clear what actually happens or why it works this way.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-19**:\

- There's also a `map_frame` parameter defined in the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html). I understand that it doesn't need to be used when we are operating our bot in the `odom` frame.
- What happens in the case of navigation using a `map`? Do we need to define both the `map_frame` and the `world_frame` parameters? If yes, do we set both of them to `map` ?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-22**:
@skpro19 see the [updated docs](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#publish-tf) regarding the `publish_tf` parameter.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-22**:
@JackB okay :-)
So, if we have set the `world_frame` as `map_frame`, we would need to use another instance of `ekf_localization` to produce the `odom -> base_link` transform?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-22**:
Also, I think, I would post a new question seeking clarification regarding `world_frame` vs `map_frame` parameters in the case of `ekf_localization`.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-22**:
Yes exactly, you need two instances of the EKF node. This is implied in my answer, and well documented in the package documentation. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Strictly, per [rep-105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), the odom frame must be continuous whereas the map frame does not need to be. This is also explained by Tom Moore himself in his [talk about robot_localization](https://vimeo.com/142624091) (around ~4:21)

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2021-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on 2021-02-22**:
exactly this. Problem with map as the world frame is, that the transformation between map and odom can jump based on localization algorithms.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-22**:
@Akhil Kurup what is the difference between the `map_frame` and the `world_frame`? If we are running a turtlebot simulation in `Gazebo`, what would be the values of `map_frame` and `world_frame` ?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-22**:
Agreed on your point, but is this what the question asked for?

**Comment by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on 2021-02-22**:
@skpro19 take a look at the examples in their [gihub repo](https://github.com/weihsinc/robot_localization/blob/master/params/ekf_imu.yaml) They have a complete section about when you need to set which frame.

And like @JackB said u use /map for the world frame only if you want robot_localization to build the map->odom transform (This is usually the case when using gps). Then something else needs to build odom->base like another robot_localization instance with different inputs (like encoder, imu etc.).

Map_frame odom_frame and base_link_frame gives robot localization the base structure like defined in rep105, meaning map is the fixed frame that contains your map, odom is the frame where your robot publishes the odometry data base_link is obviously the base of your robot to which most sensors will be attached.

The additional world_frame specifies the frame to which robot_localization builds the transform and in your case probably odom

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-02-22**:
@skpro19 the map frame and the world frame "can" be the same for a turtlebot sim in gazebo, but this depends on your application. Unfortunately, without knowing your use case, I cannot give you a generic answer. In larger applications, ones using GPS for example, the world frame can be something like utm whereas the map frame is the gps frame and the odom frame can be from robot_localization (continuous fusion).

@JackB I believe the last part of the question `when should we use odom and when should we use map?` is asking for clarification on when either frames are being used.